# Submitting information about each element from a large list selection from angular to a server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm completely new in angular, and I want to select a large set of list elements, and then submit the id's of each list element to the server. What I do is that I pack the list id's in a request URI, and, perhaps an obvious problem is that the URI quickly becomes too large. The question is therefore : Is it possible to inform a stateless server about such selections in an efficient way, and if so, how can I do this ?

Edit :

I want to get data from the server based on the list id's

Comment: Use post request to submit the data..

Comment: You can wrap all your id as a JSON like {data : ['id1', 'id2', 'id3' ....]} and submit this data to server using POST request. In AngularJS using can use this approach by inject $http service to your controller or service. About $http service, you can take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should get your data submitted to backend. Then you can check the JSON data and formulate a query accordingly. Then you send it back in the response. The responses statusHeader will determine if the .success() or the .error() branch get executed after the post.
Hope that helps

```
angular.module('app')

.controller('SubmitCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {

    $scope.submit = function(){
        $http.post(backend-url, yourJSONData)
        .success(function(){
            //do something
        })
        .error(function(){
            // do something
        })
    };

}])
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helps. I'm going to use post instead of get :)